# Nested UIView animation slows down view loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a method that generates an animation of the following kind:

```
 -(void)loadButtonView{

AppDelegate *delegateVariable = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIView *scrollButtonPlaceHolder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 230, 312,320)];
[scrollButtonPlaceHolder setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255.0 green:153.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
scrollButtonPlaceHolder.tag = 999;
scrollButtonPlaceHolder.layer.cornerRadius = 10; // this value vary as per your desire
scrollButtonPlaceHolder.clipsToBounds = YES;
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i ++) {
    NSString *prodName = nil;
    UIImage *img = nil;
if([delegateVariable.archiveArray count] >= i ){
    PriceMatchDetails *pmd =  [delegateVariable.archiveArray objectAtIndex:[delegateVariable.archiveArray count]-i];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pmd.imageURL];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    prodName = pmd.productName;
}else{
    prodName = @"N.A";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/LYFebhz.png"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];


}

    CGFloat x1 = 20;
    CGFloat y1 = 20;

    if (i%2 == 1) {
        if(i ==3){
            y1 = y1 +150;
        }

    }else if (i%2 == 0){
        if(i == 2){
            x1 = x1 + 150;
        }else{
            x1 = x1 + 150;
            y1 = y1 +150;
        }

    }


   UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x1,y1, 120, 120);
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10; // this value vary as per your desire
    button.clipsToBounds = YES;



    //[self performSelector:(SEL) withObject:(id) afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)]
    [self animateButton:button andLabelString:prodName andimage:img];
    [scrollButtonPlaceHolder addSubview:button];

}



[self.view addSubview:scrollButtonPlaceHolder];

}


-(void)animateButton:(UIButton *)button1 andLabelString:(NSString *)labelText andimage:(UIImage *)btnImage{\
int randNum = rand() % (7 -5) + 5;
button1.alpha = 1.0;
[button1 setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[UIView animateWithDuration:randNum delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^(void) {

                     button1.alpha = 0.0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:randNum delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                      animations:^(void) {
                                           button1.alpha = 1.0;
                                          [button1 setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                                          [button1 setTitle:labelText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                                          button1.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:8.0];
                                          button1.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
                                          button1.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                          [UIView animateWithDuration:randNum delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                                           animations:^(void) {
                                                               button1.alpha = 0.0;


                                                           }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                               [button1 setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                                                               [self animateButton:button1 andLabelString:labelText andimage:btnImage];
                                                               }];

                                      }];


                 }];
}
```

This method is called under -(void)ViewDiDAppear

When I present this page using the presentViewController delegate method as

```
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainVC"];
  vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
  [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

using an IBAction. When I press that button, this loadButtonView method slows down the transition. 
On launch the same view controller displays first and the new scrollButtonPlaceHolder is added to the view separately after the view appear. But the transition still wait for loadButtonView to start. Any suggestions on how to make this view to load slowly after the ViewController is displayed?

Comment: Have you considered using blocks?

Comment: also, I don't think that properties like backgroundImage or title are animated

Comment: @nikans If I use a block for loadButtonView and add it to the queue, where should I start the NSOperation on [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];?